# Can not handle string copy in ANSI C

Tags: c

I wrote a program in ANSI C to remove the double quote in front and in the end of a string, so `"Hello, world"` would become `Hello, world`:

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char* removeQuotes(char str[]) {
    int i = 1;
    int len = strlen(str) - 2;
    char * tmp = (char*) malloc (sizeof(char) * len);
    for (;i<=len;++i ) {
        tmp[i-1] = str[i];
    }
    return tmp;
}

int main(void) {
    char str[] = "Hello, world";
    char * abc = removeQuotes(str);
    printf("Inside the quotes is: %s length: %d\n"
            "Original is: %s length: %d", abc, strlen(abc), str, strlen(str));
    return 0;
}
```

In IDEOne (http://ideone.com/Iybuk) I get the correct answer. But GCC gives me something weird:

```
U→┬↓ length: 22es is: ello, worlESSOR_↑
Original is: Hello, world length: 12
```

It happens only when the string contains a space. It works fine with "Helloworld" or something like that.
Any robust method to get it work correctly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- You have not allocated enough space for the null terminator.
- You don't add the null terminator to the end of your result.
- Your source string doesn't actually contain quotes.

Comment: +1 for spotting the fact there are no quotes (and the other two issues too). I caught all of them too, but you obviously type much faster. :) I'd give you an extra +1 if I could for not providing code to fix, since it appears to be a homework assignment.

Comment: Actually my program is to get the string from stdin, I have to change it to take a pre-defined string because IDEOne can't handle input.
Maybe you're right about the null terminator.
@KenWhite : No it is not my homework. I'm learning C by myself and do exercises for fun.

Comment: @crazyfffan, if you don't post your **real** code, how do you expect people to help you figure out what's wrong? Your code sample shows nothing about `stdin`, and your text doesn't mention it either; people answer based on what your question says. (And at least one of your previous questions contains the `homework` tag, and this reads like a homework assignment, which is why both Michael and I mentioned it.)

Comment: @KenWhite My real code didn't work in IDEOne so I had to modify it a bit, but the problem  was the same. With or without the double quotes, what my code was really supposed to do was to take out one character in the front and one character in the end. So the problem was exactly as other people had spotted out: the NULL character. The double quotes are really not a big deal.

Answer (score 1):

In C strings are terminated by a null character, that means `'\0'`.

You didn't terminate string in `removeQuotes()`, this is the correct version:

```
char* removeQuotes(char str[]) {
    int i = 1;
    int len = strlen(str) - 2;
    char * tmp = (char*) malloc (sizeof(char) * (len + 1));
    for (;i<=len;++i ) {
        tmp[i-1] = str[i];
    }
    tmp[len] = '\0';
    return tmp;
}
```

Also, your string actually didn't contain quotes and you do not check if the string you pass to `removeQuotes` contain any quotes.

Comment: Thanks for the code, it works as expected. This is only the help function I took out from my bigger project and there is another function that checks if the string contains double quotes or not.

Answer (score 0):

In your `removeQuotes` function you underallocate memory for the resulting string and write an extra character past the buffer.

The string `"Hello world"` doesn't actually contain any quotes. You'd have to declare it as `"\"Hello world\""` to have the string you had in mind. In any case, the string resulting from your quote removal has the same number of characters as the input one. You lose the first character, because you never copy it, and the last one gets written past the buffer (and it would be written there, clobbering memory, even if it were a quote mark.

Why do you need to do this anyway? Do you believe that C strings are created with quote characters in the first and last positions of the character array?

Answer (score 0):

Keep a '\0' in temp string. otherwise it will not know that it is a string.

Comment: It will not know, where the string ends. If something is a string or not is assumed by your program and not checked anywhere.

Comment: when you printf("%s",string) printf assumes that there is a null character at the end. otherwise it has no mechanism to check the end. otherwise you get garbage values to the fullsize.

Comment: That's what I said. You wrote "will not know that it is a string", what is very imprecise.

Comment: How would you express this idea?

Comment: Maybe by saying "When you 1printf("%s",string)`, `printf` assumes that there is a null character at the end. otherwise it has no mechanism to know where to end the string. Without a null character, you get garbage values to the fullsize."